# How to add a telegram bot to a telegram group that im not an admin of

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

How to add a telegram bot to a telegram group that im not an admin of I did it before 1 year or 2 years ago. But i tried today and i wasn't able to add the bot to any group that i wasn't an admin. Is there any way to do this? if yes how?

Comment: You can't add bot to the group where you not admin. Telegram may remove this because bot may violate privacy of groups by spamming or other issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't add your bot to another group just like that. What you can do is create a deep linking URL and then share that URL to ask users to add your bot to any group they are part of.

```
https://t.me/usernameofyourbot?startgroup=test
```

If anyone clicks on this URL then telegram will ask them to select any group from their group list and then on selection, will add your bot to that particular group if that user has permission to do so